# ¿Cómo comparo una variable con los elementos de un Array?

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, bucles

Como hago para comparar 1 variable con los elementos de un array para saber si la condición se cumple o no.
(si el parámetro de `while` es diferente a los elementos de `movieList`, entonces vuelva a ingresar el nombre de la pelicula)

```
alert("Welcome to Cinepolis");

var movieList = ['Spider Man', 'Superman', 'Dragon Ball Super', 'La era del hielo', 'xvideos'];

while (???) {
  var movie = prompt("enter a movie");
}
```

Comment: Cuando incias el while aun no tienes nada que comparar... Podrias entonces hacerlo con un do-while. `do { ... } while(!movieList.includes(movie))`

Comment: entiendo, tratare de hacerlo como me sugieres, gracias mi brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar el método [**`includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) para determinar si dicho elemento se encuentra en los elementos del arreglo **`movieList`**. Veamos:

```js
function BuscarPeliculas(pelicula) {
let movieList = ['Spider Man', 'Superman', 'Dragon Ball Super', 'La era del hielo'];
  // si el parámetro "pelicula" se encuentra en los elementos del arreglo "movieList", entrará al while.
  while (movieList.includes(pelicula)) {
    return "se encontró la película!";
  }
  // de lo contrario, se saldrá del while y retornará esto.
  return "no se encontró la película";
}

console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Spider Man"));
console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Spider Man 2"));
console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Dragon Ball Super"));
console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Dragon Ball Super 2"));
```

También puedes usar el método [**`indexOf()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) para buscar el índice en el que se encuentra dicho elemento, si encuentra, retornará la posición del elemento encontrado, de lo contrario retornará **`-1`**, y con esto evaluamos en el **`while`**:

```js
function BuscarPeliculas(pelicula) {
let movieList = ['Spider Man', 'Superman', 'Dragon Ball Super', 'La era del hielo'];
  // si el parámetro "pelicula" se encuentra en los elementos del arreglo "movieList", entrará al while.
  while (movieList.indexOf(pelicula) >= 0) {
    return "se encontró la película!";
  }
  // de lo contrario, se saldrá del while y retornará esto.
  return "no se encontró la película";
}

console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Spider Man"));
console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Spider Man 2"));
console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Dragon Ball Super"));
console.log(BuscarPeliculas("Dragon Ball Super 2"));
```

Comment: gracias Cris223511.dev por tu comentario, fuiste de gran ayuda !!!